# Bedrock edition raid farms

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I’ve been wanting to make a raid farm for a while - my friend has one and it is extremely profitable.
I found a pillagers outpost near a village - but the village was glitched. The villagers wouldn’t enter their houses when I rang the village bell, so it was extremely difficult to trap them.
Also, half the village spawned at the top of an extremely tall mountain. The pillagers, evokers, ravagers and vindicators tend to spawn on the side of it, making them extremely hard to kill.
So I have a couple of questions:

1. Any general advice on raids? I don’t have much experience with them and am unsure of strategies, gear and villager protection measures.
2. Do you have a seed that has better opportunities for raid farms? Preferably the pillagers outpost and village would be relatively close together, though this isn’t a necessity.
   Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any general advice on raids?

First of all, you need to get the Bad Omen effect, which is kind of difficult if you already won a raid. Then head to the same village and protect those villagers.

You have to be extremely prepared, and for that, you need lots of food (I suggest cooked) and good armor. Shields, totems and potions are optional.

I already talked about using beacons to win at raids, and that is optional as well.

> Do you have a seed that has better opportunities for raid farms?

I actually have a world and I was looking for jungle wood. I find it interesting that somehow, I got to a village, and the outpost is almost inside it, though I'm not sure if it is the best spot for raid farms. Sadly, I can't seem to find the village anymore though but I was somewhere around `x = 10000, z = 10000`. You might find it there somewhere.

The seed for it is `1832397879` in *v.1.16.4*.

Answer (score 2):

If anything, walls might have the most use. Put a wall protecting the inside of the village, but make sure to have the spawn points outside of the wall. From experience, if you are 1 block off the wall, the vindicator (my opinion-hardest part of raids) cannot hit you. With a shield, you can effectively make vindicators and pillagers free kills. For the second part of your question, I suggest asking your friend for the seed, that way you can use the seed that seems to work pretty well. Edit: I suggest doing a raid without the wall that way you can find the spawn points of the illagers and build the wall accordingly.